# Using the font awesome icon as a button

Tags: bootstrap-4, font-awesome

I am trying to use the font awesome icon. This appears too small for me
and when I mouseover it disappears.

```
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-5 mx-auto">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input class="form-control border-end-0 border rounded-pill" type="text" value="" id="example-text-input" >
                    <span>
                        <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary bg-white border-bottom-0 border rounded-pill ms-n5" type="button">
                            <i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i>
                        </button>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

How can I make this arrow bigger and remove the mouseover effect that is hiding the icon?
I will need to use the onclick event of this button at some point.

Answer (score 1):

The `.btn-outline-*` variants invert the colors on hover.
Just replace `.btn-outline-secondary` with `.text-secondary`.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-AYmEC3Yw5cVb3ZcuHtOA93w35dYTsvhLPVnYs9eStHfGJvOvKxVfELGroGkvsg+p" crossorigin="anonymous" />

<div class="container">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-5 mx-auto">
      <div class="input-group">
        <input class="form-control border-end-0 border rounded-pill" type="text" value="" id="example-text-input">
        <span>
          <button class="btn text-secondary bg-white border-bottom-0 border rounded-pill ms-n5" type="button">
            <i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i>
          </button>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```